# Formatting numbers in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get use data to write an URL and scrape the data from a website. 
My function is on github : https://github.com/blaquans/RInsee/blob/master/R/inflation.R.

It works fine with small numbers but it does not work with large numbers :

```
> inflation(input = 4000, input.currency = "Euro", input.year = 2004, output.currency = "Euro", output.year = 2012)
http://www.insee.fr/fr/themes/calcul-pouvoir-achat.asp?sommeDepart=4000&deviseDepart=Euro&anneeDepart=2004&deviseArrivee=Euro&anneeArrivee=2012
[1] 4569.57
> inflation(input = 400000, input.currency = "Euro", input.year = 2004, output.currency = "Euro", output.year = 2012)
ERROR 
http://www.insee.fr/fr/themes/calcul-pouvoir-achat.asp?sommeDepart=4e+05&deviseDepart=Euro&anneeDepart=2004&deviseArrivee=Euro&anneeArrivee=2012
[1] NA
```

The reason is that R transform 400000 in 4e+06 and doesn't write the good URL. How can I force R to write 400000 instead of 4e+06 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `options(scipen =)`

```
inflation <- function(input, input.currency, input.year, output.currency, output.year) {
  oldscipen <- options('scipen')$scipen
  options(scipen = 999)

  require("RCurl")
  tx <- getURL(paste("http://www.insee.fr/fr/themes/calcul-pouvoir-achat.asp?sommeDepart=",input, "&deviseDepart=",input.currency,"&anneeDepart=",input.year, "&deviseArrivee=",output.currency, "&anneeArrivee=",output.year, sep = ""))
  patrick <- ".*<strong class=\"resultat\">([[:digit:][:blank:],]+)[[:blank:]eurosfracin]+</strong>.*"
  if (grepl(pattern = patrick, x = tx) == TRUE){
    out <- sub(pattern = patrick , replacement = "\\1", x = tx)
    out <- as.numeric(gsub( pattern = "[[:blank:]]", replacement = "", x = gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", x = out)))
    }
  else {
    cat("ERROR \n")
    out <- NA
    }
  options(scipen = oldscipen)

  return(out)
  }
```

Testing your example:

```
> inflation(input = 4000, input.currency = "Euro", input.year = 2004, output.currency = "Euro", output.year = 2012)
Loading required package: RCurl
Loading required package: bitops
[1] 4569.57
> 
> inflation(input = 400000, input.currency = "Euro", input.year = 2004, output.currency = "Euro", output.year = 2012)

[1] 456956.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Is your solution different from format(input, scientific = FALSE)

Comment: That should work also and maybe easier if you are only inputting once.